# How to disallow URLs containing fragment identifier or a hash symbol?

Tags: robots.txt

Can we disallow URLs contain `#!/xxxx` in robots.txt? For Example:

```
/peach-polyester#!/inventory/linen-rentals/
```

Comment: It isn't possible for robots or browser crawl hash URLs in the traditional sense because the information after the hash isn't even sent to your server.  All your server ever sees is a request for `/peach-polyester` while everything after the hash is client-side only.  Preventing hash URLs from getting crawled doesn't make much sense because they are NEVER crawled.  Are you trying to prevent something else such as bot rendering of these URLs or indexing of these URLs?